# C# Project. Trying to find the average, Smallest number, largest number and number of numbers in a .txt file

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to Write a C# console app that will take input from a text file of numbers. From the numbers I need to find the number of numbers, the largest of the numbers, the smallest of the numbers and the average of the numbers.

```cs
int NumberCounter = 0;
string NumberLines;

//Code to Read the file and display Each Line seperately.  
System.IO.StreamReader NumbersFile = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"c:\Numbers.txt");
while ((NumberLines = NumbersFile.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(NumberLines);
    NumberCounter++;
}

NumbersFile.Close();
System.Console.WriteLine("There Are {0} lines.", NumberCounter);
Console.ReadLine();
```

As you can see, I've only got the count figured out right now. Trying to use any sort of equation to compare the Streamreader to anything else results in a type mismatch error. I'm a beginner here, so I'm a little lost.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So each line contains a single number?

Comment: You need to read about collections, generic collections to start with.

Comment: If each line is a single number <2x10^9, you can use [Int32.Parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.parse) or [Int32.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse) to convert it into an int.

Comment: Hey there! This looks like you're seeking someone to solve a problem for you - stack overflow is more about specific errors and how to solve them, this has a very simple solution with a bit of googling, you may want to review the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask section

Comment: Please define number. Is it an integer? If it's a real number please specify the format.

Answer (score 4):

You could read all the values into a list and then iterate over them to calculate your various values, or you can do something like the following that can process extremely large files with ease:

```
string NumberLines;
var largest = int.MinValue;
var smallest = int.MaxValue;
var count = 0;
var total = 0;
using(var NumbersFile = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"c:\Numbers.txt"))
{
  while ((NumberLines = NumbersFile.ReadLine()) != null)
  {
    var value = int.Parse(NumberLines);
    count++;
    largest = Math.Max(largest,value);
    smallest = Math.Min(smallest,value);
    total += value;
  }
}
var average = total/count;
```

If you aren't tied to the StreamReader, then I would use the following:

```
var largest = int.MinValue;
var smallest = int.MaxValue;
var count = 0;
var total = 0;
foreach(var line in File.ReadLines(@"c:\Numbers.txt"))
{
  var value = int.Parse(line);
  count++;
  largest = Math.Max(largest,value);
  smallest = Math.Min(smallest,value);
  total += value;
}
var average = total/count;
```

Comment: This is the most efficient as it only iterates once, but definitely less readable than LINQ.

Comment: Yes, it will use significantly less CPU, and an insignificant fixed amount of memory.

Answer (score 2):

you can do this:

```
var text = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\Numbers.txt");
var numbers = text.Where(l=>int.TryParse(l, out int _)).Select(l => int.Parse(l)).ToList();
var max = numbers.Max();
var min = numbers.Min();
var average = numbers.Average();
var total = numbers.Count();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [File.ReadAllLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?view=netframework-4.8) along with [Int32.Parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.parse?view=netframework-4.8) and then use `Linq` for calculating [Min](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.min?view=netframework-4.8),[Max](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.max?view=netframework-4.8) , [Count](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count?view=netframework-4.8) and [Average](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.average?view=netframework-4.8).

For Example,

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);    
var numbers = lines.Select(x=>Int32.Parse(x)); // Or Double.Parse or... Depending on expected numeric type
var min = numbers.Min();
var max = numbers.Max();
var average = numbers.Average();
var count = numbers.Count();
```

Comment: I would prefer code that used `var`, as you suggested, changing the code to handle doubles (or another datatype), would be as trivial as changing the Int32.Parse to Double.Parse.

Comment: @RobertMcKee but for answering a question on here, it isn't clear what any of those methods return.

Comment: Also, I disagree with the sentiment; ok in the context of these 5 lines of code you would be correct, but in general terms changing the data type of a variable would often break your code.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay It is fine that you disagree with that sentiment, but it is your opinion.  One that I don't share, and one that even the resharper team doesn't share (it will recommend you change them to var by default).  If you care what the type is (rare), it is trivial to determine, or hover your mouse over it and VS will tell you.  In every other case, the type is just noise and distracts from the purpose of the code.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay The usage of var or explicit types are purely developer preferences. I personally prefer var because for me, it increases readability by removing the type names which as Robert termed it, could be noisy

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at `File.ReadLines` which returns an `IEnumerable<string>`.

The `IEnumerable` can be used with LINQ which has handy methods for aggregation:

```
IEnumerable<string> numberStrings = File.ReadLines(@"c:\Numbers.txt");
IEnumerable<double> numbers = numberStrings.Select(s => double.Parse(s));

double smallest = numbers.Min();
double largest = numbers.Max();
double average = numbers.Average();
```

Answer (score 2):

You should start off by declaring a `List<int>` before your `while` loop in which to save the numbers you find in your file.

```
List<int> numbersInFile = new List<int>();
```

Then, you need to parse the content of each line to check if it is formatted as a valid number, in which case you'll want to add it to the aforementioned list.

```
if (int.TryParse(NumberLines, out int number))
{
    numbersInFile.Add(number);
}
```

Finally, the `List<>` structure already implements handy methods such as `.Average()`, `.Min()` and `.Max()` which will return the values you seek.

```
int max = numbersInFile.Max();
```

Answer (score -1):

I think if you will need in List,Stack,Queue,massive and m. I will use massive. So get Number, get digits of Number(in loop  while number isn't 0: for it get number mod 10, divide number by 10),write Number to massive,getting Max,Average,Min,Count of massive by the same named functions. ))))
SO this is my code:

```cs
int NumberCounter = 0;
int[] massive = new int[1000]
string NumberLines;

//Code to Read the file and display Each Line seperately.  
System.IO.StreamReader NumbersFile = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"c:\Numbers.txt");
while ((NumberLines = NumbersFile.ReadLine()) != null)
{
   System.Console.WriteLine(NumberLines);
int number = int.Parse(NumberLines);
int number1 = number;
while(number1!=0)
{
s = number1 %1 0;
number1 /= 10;
Console.WriteLine(s);
}
massive[NumberCounter]=number;
    NumberCounter++;
}
NumbersFile.Close();
Console.WriteLine(massive.Average());
Console.WriteLine(massive.Max());
Console.WriteLine(massive.Min());



System.Console.WriteLine("There Are {0} lines.", NumberCounter);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your answer. What is a massive? And how do you declare it?

Comment: I forgot to write it Sorry. :(((

Comment: I deleted massive.